# NHibernate.Envers entity properties change log

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate-envers

I want to implement something like change log with NHibernate.Envers. How I can achieve this in most elegant way? Suppose we have **blog (name)** and **post (body, createdat)** entities. Blog has many posts. I need to get history of blog changes:

```
modified: name changed from 'a' to 'b'
added post: body 'example', createdat 24.02.2013

modified: name changed from 'b' to 'c'
post modified: body changed from 'example' to 'sample'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Envers, and I suppose NEnvers is the same, there isn't any specific support for this use case. You need to read the desired range of revisions of an entity (could be all), getting a list of historic entities and compare in-VM.

See also:

[Getting modified properties by revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830956/getting-modified-properties-by-revision/14853016#14853016)